# Percentage of tenure track positions promoted to full professors

Tags: career-path, professorship, assistant-professor

I wonder if there are statistics on the overall percentage of people promoted from tenure track positions (assistant professor) to full professor in fields like mathematics and science (first-rate institution is OK).

Comment: Closely related, maybe duplicate: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/34924/what-is-the-promotion-rate-of-professors-in-united-states/43544#43544 and https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/568/what-percent-of-assistant-professors-generally-receive-tenure-and-how-does-this

Comment: Both do not tell the exact statistics. Maybe there are not any.

Comment: The percentage itself has little value. Say something about why you want such information and you might get more informative answers. The percentage means very little in any individual situation, I think.

Comment: Nothing special, just for curiosity. I believe the rate is much low nowadays than that of 20 years ago because the conditions have been much improved in university

Comment: Highly variable. Top universities often have a lower percentage who are promoted in place, but those missing out there often are tenured elsewhere.

Comment: Is this sense of the verb "prompt" foreign to me, or just a confusion with "promote"?

Comment: Of course, top universities have high competition and so lower rate of promotion. Often very top departments find most full professors elsewhere, and rarely promote their own assistant (associate) professors to full level.

Comment: See my answer here https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/25949/what-books-biographies-or-survival-guides-are-helpful-for-men-in-education-in/25983#25983 the data for the UK are collected by hesa

Comment: it stands to reason that as jobs get harder to get, so do promotions, as schools can just keep raising the bar everywhere.

Comment: It depends a lot on university and country as well. In some European countries, many successful academics retire at the level of associate professor. I don't think this can be answered in the abstract.

Comment: Do you actually mean "get tenure", or do you actually care specifically about further promotion beyond tenure? In the U.S., as many people here know, but not everyone, most assoc. prof. positions in the U.S. are "with tenure", while few assist. prof. positions are. So the genuine question might be more like "how many people who get a tenure-track position do get tenure?" Or is that not the point?

Comment: I'd like to know both, i.e. percentages of assistant profs who get tenure as well as those who get to full profs.

Comment: _Of course, top universities have high competition and so lower rate of promotion_ — [citation needed]!

Comment: Ivy league school, Stanford, MIT, Yale, U Chicago, Caltech and etc, normally find full professors elsewhere, and rarely promote their own assistant (associate) professors to full level. In other words, you have to be internationally established before being appointed as full professors at these institutions.